# Web-service able to return IDictionary on Local Machine but not on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, asmx

I have an `asmx` web-service with a method returning a dictionary object, On my local machine using the test server it works fine. However when I publish it to the production server I get an error that it isn’t supported because it implements `IDictionary`. I looked around a bit and it seems that by default this is the case (that it isn’t supported), and so I guess that is the correct behavior.  What I would like to know if why it works on my local machine, and if there is some setting that I can apply to get it to work on the server.

If it makes a difference the dictionary is using a string as the key and a custom object array for the value.

For now I’m able to get around it by serializing my dictionary as a string (using `JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize`) and returning that, but ideally I would like to return the dictionary straight (or barring that at least understand what’s going on).

Comment: Switch to WCF, the DataContractSerializer is capable to serialize dictionaries out of the box.

Comment: I do plan on switching to WCF at some point, I ran into some problems trying to setup a WCF service (I had it working on my local machine but not on the server). At any rate for now I'm using ASMX since it "just works" (or at least mostly) out of the box (for my needs at least).

Comment: Write a post on your problems and someone will help for sure. WCF is so much better than ASMX that you unnecessarily lose too much. Note that WCF works in IIS too so that in fact, your web services can be exposed as WCFs in the same way you expose them as ASMXes.

Comment: I would like to, I just need to get around and devote some time to doing so. At the moment in my case I'm basically just consuming my webserices in JavaScript and I haven't seen a real benefit to using WCF over ASMX for this purpose (and its much easier to set up a ASMX).